# Apple iTunes Affiliate Program - Song link metadata?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, itunes

I have an app that plays music from the user's iTunes library on the device. Without going into the details of the "Whys" behind what I am doing, I just need to know how to automatically get the iTunes store link from each song.  So in the app, I will show a song list. I want a "Download" button next to each song. When the user presses that button it opens up the song in iTunes to be purchased. Is there a way to dynamically find the links to those songs, or do the links have to be pre-programmed into the app?

I was hoping any official iTunes music would have an iTunes download link/other useful meta data associated with it.

Again these songs are never the same on all devices because they are coming from the users library.

Maybe there is some search function I can do?

Comment: I have no idea why you would provide a download link for a song that is already on the users media library (and probably already bought it). But you should go with the iTunes search API mentioned by Jeroen Bouma and search in the iTunes store for the meta data.

Answer (score 1):

It is not exactly automatically (though for the user it will be), but with the title of the track you could search it using the [iTunes Store Web Service Search API](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html).

This will return a JSON response with the link to the song in the iTunes store (along with some other useful metadata).

Answer (score 0):

I've got his same problem. Considering using EchoNest to actually identify a track from its audio content, then using the returned values (title, album, etc.) from EN to query iTunes API for the track in the Store.

This is based on the assumption that the user's track metadata is not reliable, and has the added benefit that you can fill in any missing data that the user may not have (eg. album art)

Any other ideas?